# Looping through unique column values and copying another column into a new matrix

Tags: r

I haven't been using loops in R much and am trying to do something, which I'd imagine is best done with a loop. Here's a sample dataset:

```
structure(list(Subject = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 501, 501, 
501, 501, 501, 501, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 502, 509, 509, 509, 
509, 509, 509), Stimuli.ACC = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Stimuli.CRESP = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 400L, 401L, 
402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L), class = "data.frame")
```

I also have this empty data frame:

```
Acc_vector <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow=6))
```

I'd like to loop through the unique values of `Subject` and copy the full length of the column `Stimuli.ACC` for that subject into the corresponding column of `Acc_vector`. For example, this way, the 6 rows for subject 501's column `Stimuli.ACC` would be copied into `Acc_vector[,2]`.

How I imagine it is something like:

```
for (i in 1:(length(unique(CS_data_acc$Subject)))) {
Acc_vector[,i] <- CS_data_acc %>% group_by(Subject) %>% 
  print(CS_data_acc$Stimuli.ACC)
  }
```

But can't get my head around how to do it, so that it works. Of course, I could subset and do them one-by-one for each participants, but you can imagine the dataset is pretty large and doing this manually would be prone to errors too much.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `for` loop to replace the values in a second data frame, one base R approach would be the following (note, my interpretation is that each column should be a unique study ID, not row - please correct me if that is wrong):

```
Acc_vector <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 6)) # second df, per OP

names(Acc_vector) <- unique(CS_data_acc$Subject) # name second DF

for(xx in seq_len(length(unique(CS_data_acc$Subject)))){
  temp <- CS_data_acc$Stimuli.ACC[CS_data_acc$Subject %in% unique(CS_data_acc$Subject)[xx]]
  Acc_vector[seq_along(temp), xx] <- temp
}

# output

#   500 501 502 509 NA
# 1   1   1   1   1  0
# 2   1   1   1   1  0
# 3   1   1   1   1  0
# 4   1   1   1   1  0
# 5   1   1   1   1  0
# 6   0   1   1   1  0
```

Note that if you dont need to pre-specify the number of columns and rows in your second data frame, pre-specifying your second data frame may put undue constraints on it. For instance, in the example above, there are only five unique IDs but the second df specifies six columns.

For a more flexible approach, you may just want to initiate an empty data frame. In this case, the code would look like:

```
Acc_vector <- data.frame()
for(xx in seq_len(length(unique(CS_data_acc$Subject)))){
  temp <- CS_data_acc$Stimuli.ACC[CS_data_acc$Subject %in% unique(CS_data_acc$Subject)[xx]]
  Acc_vector[seq_along(temp), xx] <- temp
}
names(Acc_vector) <- unique(CS_data_acc$Subject)

#  500 501 502 509
#1   1   1   1   1
#2   1   1   1   1
#3   1   1   1   1
#4   1   1   1   1
#5   1   1   1   1
#6  NA   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation I think what you want to do is get the data in wide format. Using libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr` this is what you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('X', row_number()), .by = Subject) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, 
              values_from = Stimuli.ACC, id_cols = -Stimuli.CRESP)

#   Subject   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
#    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     500     1     1     1     1     1    NA
#2     501     1     1     1     1     1     1
#3     502     1     1     1     1     1     1
#4     509     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, Ronak! I think it would also work really well. However, my data frame is quite big and moving to wide might for this specific case be a bit confusing. The output also goes into Matlab afterwards and my code there expect different columns for each participant. In any case, thank you and I'd keep the code for future smaller dfs.